# Change scale to set bounds

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

This question is the result of forgetting to document your code...I'm having trouble setting the bounds on my ggplot legend...I'd like it to read 10 to -10 by intervals of 5 with 0 as the midpoint of course.

```
ggmap(tcsec) + 
  geom_tile(data = secmodelobscount, 
            aes(x = long, y = lat, fill = diff), 
            alpha = 0.8) + 
  ggtitle("Southeast/Caribbean\nExperimental Model Simulation - Observations") + 
  scale_fill_gradient2("Difference", low = "blue", mid = "white", high = "red", 
                       midpoint = 0, breaks = c(10, 5, 0, -5, -10))
```

What I get with this code is...

[image]

Comment: Please provide a reliable example of your data

Comment: add `limits = c(-10, 10)`